# latitude and logtitude not showing on processing when inserted on csv file

Tags: java, processing

I have a CSV file with two fields that contain latitude and longitudes. On processing, when I click an area on a 2D image map I get the coordinates but when I use these coordinates in the fields of lat and lon on my CSV file it does not show the shape it on the map.

What am I doing wrong here?

Code for the coordinates:

```
float Xcord;
float Ycord;

 void mouseClicked() {
 if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
    Xcord = pmouseX;
    Ycord = pmouseY;
  println(Xcord + "," + Ycord);
}
}
```

Comment: is the `draw()` loop running?

Comment: I've created a for loop in the draw function.

Comment: Shown as is, this code should give you coordinates (maybe not lat-long, but coordinates). The comportment you're describing may be the result of another manipulation.